# NiFi fails to launch due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-nifi, illegalargumentexception, md5sum

I have been trying to launch NiFi, but everytime I do so I get the following error:

> 2019-03-06 18:53:46,935 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to
>   launch NiFi due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: md5 MessageDigest not
>   available java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: md5 MessageDigest not
>   available
>       at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker.calculateMd5sum(NarUnpacker.java:419)
>       at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker.unpackNar(NarUnpacker.java:228)
>       at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker.unpackNars(NarUnpacker.java:123)
>       at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:128)
>       at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:71)
>       at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:296) Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: md5 MessageDigest not
>   available
>       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
>       at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
>       at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:167)
>       at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker.calculateMd5sum(NarUnpacker.java:407)
>       ... 5 common frames omitted 2019-03-06 18:53:46,939 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web
>   server... 2019-03-06 18:53:46,940 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi
>   Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).

I understand this is coming from "calculateMd5sum " function that calculates md5 sum of a specified file. However, I have made no changes to any of Nars neither have I added any custom nars. The same instance did launch before.

I have also tried to start afresh by extracting the setup again, however I face the same error. I fail to understand why the issue is coming up all of a sudden. Please help!

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The error is saying that your JDK/JRE does not have access to the MD5 algorithm.

Comment: @BryanBende I am using java version "1.8.0_121"
With my JAVA_HOME pointed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"

Answer (score 0):

I got it. 
My java home pointed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
changed the path to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121"

It works fine now.
Thanks @BryanBende